# ValueError: math domain error when using math.sqrt()

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to make a program to check for Herone Triangle in range for `tries` to `max_tries` but `math.sqrt()` is giving me a headache

This is my code

```
import math
max_tries = 10000
tries = 1
half_perimeter = ((tries * 3) + 3) / 2

for num in range(tries,max_try,1):
    area = math.sqrt(half_perimeter * (half_perimeter - tries) * (half_perimeter - tries - 1) * (half_perimeter - tries - 2))
    if isinstance(area, int ) == True:
        print (tries)
        tries = tries + 1
    else :
        tries = tries + 1
```

Whenever I run, I get `ValueError: math domain error` from python. What is wrong with my code? The whole error returned is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\phong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Herone Triangle.py", line 9, in <module>
area = math.sqrt(half_perimeter * (half_perimeter - tries) * (half_perimeter - tries - 1) * (half_perimeter - tries - 2))
ValueError: math domain error
```

I'm still a script kiddy, just got into Python. Thanks guys

Comment: You're taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: Your code does not define the variable `max_try` which makes it more difficult for us to run your code or find the exact problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Since `half_perimeter` is initialized outside the loop, it will always have the value `((1 * 3) + 3) / 2 = (3 + 3) / 2 = 6 / 2 = 3`. Then, inside the loop, some of the factors will become negative in some circumstances and, in a subset of those, an odd number of factors will become negative. This leads to the whole argument of `sqrt` becoming negative, which leads to a domain error since `math.sqrt` only works when the result is real.

Comment: This should be the main error. Put the evaluation of `half_perimeter` inside the loop and at least the Heron formula is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't really understand the way `for` loop works. It executes all code 'inside' it and then (in this case) adds one to `tries`.

For this reason on each iteration you add 2 to `tries` - at first in your code and then the for loop iteslf does it.

I also believe you need to count `half_perimeter` again on each iteration - otherwise it is always the same and you run into math error (square root of negative number).

Answer (score 0):

This equation at some point giving negative number **half_perimeter * (half_perimeter - tries) * (half_perimeter - tries - 1) * (half_perimeter - tries - 2)** thus math.sqrt() invocation is returning error.